# Required properties are missing from object: qnaRuntimeEndpoint

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-qna-maker

I can't deploy the QnA maker via ARM template

Following my template

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "accounts_MyBot_QnAMaker_name": {
            "defaultValue": "MyBot-QnAMaker",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.CognitiveServices/accounts",
            "apiVersion": "2016-02-01-preview",
            "name": "[parameters('accounts_MyBot_QnAMaker_name')]",
            "location": "westus",
            "sku": {
                "name": "S0"
            },
            "kind": "QnAMaker",
            "properties": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the status error message I receive

```
"statusMessage": {
            "error": {
                "code": "ApiPropertiesInvalid",
                "message": "The given 'apiProperties' '{}' is invalid. Validation errors: Required properties are missing from object: qnaRuntimeEndpoint. Path ''."
            }
        },
```

https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/6888#issuecomment-417817480

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the template this way.

Fill in the form(do not click create button) on Azure portal when create a new QnA Maker and click Automation options.

[image]

Then you will get the template and parameters. I have created a new one in this way.

[image]